# Requirements for the request for a Certificate of French Nationality from the US

Tags: france, eu, french-citizens

Will a request for a CNF (certificate of French Nationality) require that American certificates be notarized by an apostille and/or a French translation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but it seems that yes, documents not in French require a court approved translation. I believe the translation to French must be conducted first, and then what the French call "legalisation" which I believe must be carried out by the French embassy or consulate in the country where the document was issued. This is not required for some documents in the EU, but otherwise it generally is required.

Here's the relevant pages from the French government's web sites:

- Translation https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12956?lang=en
- Legalisation https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1402?lang=en
- Application for CNF https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F35509/1_0_1?idFicheParent=F1051#1_0_1